# TypeScript union type requires length

Tags: typescript

```
interface IMessage {
  value: string;
  length?: string;   // <-- why is this line necessary?
}

function saySize(message: IMessage|IMessage[]) {
  if (message instanceof Array) {
    return message.length;
  }
}
```

This snippet compiles, but requires an option `length` in `IMessage`. If it is left out, the error is:

```
unions.ts(8,24): error TS2339: Property 'length' does not exist on type 'IMessage | IMessage[]'.
```

I find this counterintuitive because I need to make the assumption that `IMessage` can be used as an array type. Is adding the optional length needed indeed, or am I making a mistake?

Comment: According to the blog entry for 1.4 (I presume that is what you are using), then the length property shouldn't be required. If you use the Type Guard pattern (slightly different to your example), then it should infer the type within that if statement. More info here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/typescript/archive/2014/11/18/what-s-new-in-the-typescript-type-system.aspx

Comment: True. It doesn't need `length` when I change the signature of saySize to `message: IMessage[]`. But then I can not use saySize for `IMessage` and `IMessage[]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no currently open issues against TypeScript 1.4 for Type Guards. Type Guards include both `typeof` and `instanceof`.

The check you use (instanceof) should cause a narrowing of type within the if-block. That should mean the `length?: string;` on your interface is not needed.

You could raise the issue here to see if it can be fixed, or if there is a special reason for arrays to be treated differently.

https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/milestones/TypeScript%201.4

In the meantime, you could use this ugly looking type assertion to avoid adding the property to your interface (as an IMessage wouldn't have that property).

```
return (<IMessage[]><any>message).length;
```

Answer (score 4):

Seems like a Bug. I've reported here : https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1587 One thing of note is that I wouldn't use `interface` with a Type Guard although that is not the source of the error here.

**UPDATE** its been fixed on `master` : https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/1657 so should be there in `1.4`